# driver = webdriver.Chrome opens browser before user executes code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a GUI application that should open without the browser opening. The browser should open only after the user clicks a button. `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`  is a global setting used by multiple classes. This is the code that starts when the application is open:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# The browser has opened before the code gets executed.
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

UPDATE: After thinking more about this I think the solution is to instantiate the 'driver' in the function called by the GUI button and then pass the driver to the other functions. So, rather than making the driver global, it will be a local variable passed as needed. I need time to try it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent this code from running before its intended time you could use a function. For example

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
def open_browser():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    return driver
```

You would then need to call this function whenever you would like to open the chrome browser. It will then return the driver and you can use it like normal.
Here is an example of using the driver once it's been created.

```py
driver = open_browser()
    driver.get('https://example.com')
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Originally I had the code running from a terminal widow with a main function and that was fine. Using the GUI however presented this problem as I wanted the user to trigger the browser opening. Thank you for the answer!